# Загрузка http страницы с отдачей тех же заголовков

Tags: php

Нужно скачать файл с чужого сервера и сразу же передать его в браузер клиента, редирект использовать нельзя, каким способом лучше поступить?

Comment: использовать любую из доступных функций скачивания файла, например.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, перечислите готовые функции, которые смогут не просто скачать файл на сервер (а для решения вопроса сохранение файла на сервере излишне), а также начать передавать его клиенту до завершения скачивания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данное решение подойдет загрузки файлов с другого домена

```
   $path="/manual/ru/function.fsockopen.php";
    $host='php.net';

    $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30) or die("error");
    fputs($fp,"GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHOST: $host\r\n\r\n");

    while(!feof($fp)){
        $chank = fgets($fp, 1000);

        if(!$head_ok){
            $head.=$chank;

            $pos = strpos($head, "\r\n\r\n");
            if($pos!== false){
               $bodyChank = substr($head, $pos+4);
               $head = substr($head, 0, $pos);

               $headersRaw = explode("\r\n", $head);

               foreach ($headersRaw as $v) {
                   header($v);
               }

               $head_ok=1;
            }
        }
        else{
            $bodyChank.=$chank;
            echo $bodyChank;
            $bodyChank = "";
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
```